# How to communicate OpenFileDialog result "FilePath" from view to view Model?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am trying to open a file dialog by pressing a button on view and view call a command "OpenFileDialog" which is defined in viewmodel. That method send a message to view to open the "Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()" and now  I want to communicate the result of OpenFileDialog to ViewModel.

**ViewModel**

```
 public ICommand OpenFileCommand {
  get { return new RelayCommand( ( ) => OpenFileCommandExecute( ), ( ) => true ); }
}

private void OpenFileCommandExecute( ) {
  Messenger.Default.Send( "OpenfileDialog" );
}
```

**View**

```
 Messenger.Default.Register( this, "OpenFileDialog", openFileDialog) ;
 private void openFileDialog(  ) {
  OpenFileDialog OFP = new OpenFileDialog( );
  var kk = OFP.ShowDialog( );      
 }
```

I want to communicate the selected file path to view model. I am using MVVM Light Toolkit and WPF. My code is not in working condition.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenFileDialog should have a Filename property that you can check after the ShowDialog() method.

**Example**

```
OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openDialog.ShowDialog();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(openDialog.Filename)) return;

string path = openDialog.Filename;
```

Then if you want it accessible on the view model just create your own property for the path in the ViewModel class and populate it with the Filename property.

Comment: I would like to know, how can populate the FileName property in ViewModel without messaging?